# java - Instead sum of the number then connect the number

Tags: java

How to reverse integer in Java?

```
    int number = 123;
    int newNumber=0;

    while (number > 0) {
        int dig = 0;
        dig = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        newNumber+=dig;

    }
    System.out.print(newNumber);
```

output:

```
6
```

but i want the number be:

```
321
```

I know how to do it with a string, but with int i can not successful.

Comment: And the question is? Int and string are two different data types, everything here is working as intended.

Comment: `3+2+1` = `6`. Use a `String` instead `int`